# AWS PutObject Connection reset

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, connection-close

My AWS Java Client is throwing

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkEOF(SSLSocketImpl.java:1541) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkWrite(SSLSocketImpl.java:1553) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:71) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.flushBuffer(AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.java:159) ~[httpcore-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
```

My code is

```
public void save(String name, byte[] file) {
    ObjectMetadata metaData = new ObjectMetadata();
    String streamMD5 = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(file));
    metaData.setContentMD5(streamMD5);
    metaData.setContentLength(file.length);

    InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(file);
    try {
        PutObjectRequest put = new PutObjectRequest(
                configuration.getBucketName(), name, stream, metaData);
        s3client.putObject(put);
    } finally {
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(stream);
    }
}
```

The s3client is a spring bean and is not garbage collected before the stream has finished uploading.  I've tried without specifying MD5 and/or content length but still has the same exception thrown.

Logging through AWS library shows:

```
10:09:15.540 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.a.h.c.protocol.RequestAddCookies - CookieSpec selected: best-match
10:09:15.540 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.a.h.c.protocol.RequestAuthCache - Auth cache not set in the context
10:09:15.540 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.a.h.c.p.RequestProxyAuthentication - Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
10:09:15.540 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG c.a.http.impl.client.SdkHttpClient - Attempt 1 to execute request
10:09:15.540 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.a.h.i.conn.DefaultClientConnection - Sending request: PUT /documeent.pdf HTTP/1.1
10:09:15.540 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "PUT /document.pdf HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
10:09:15.540 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "Host: bucket.s3.amazonaws.com[\r][\n]"
10:09:15.540 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "Authorization: AWS 123445667788=[\r][\n]"
10:09:15.540 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "User-Agent: aws-sdk-java/1.10.21 Linux/3.13.0-65-generic Java_HotSpot(TM)_Server_VM/25.60-b23/1.8.0_60[\r][\n]"
10:09:15.540 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "Date: Tue, 06 Oct 2015 09:09:15 GMT[\r][\n]"
10:09:15.663 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG com.amazonaws.internal.SdkSSLSocket - closing bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/12.34.56.78:443
10:09:15.665 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.a.h.i.conn.DefaultClientConnection - I/O error closing connection
```

I've checked that the file size (3.2M) does not exceed the max file siez for this bucket.

Get/List requests work fine and I can copy files into the S3 bucket using the s3 client tools.

Does anyone know of anything else I should check?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to pass the file as File object? In their example they do like this: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjSingleOpJava.html

Comment: Yay!  That works, thanks.  Pity to have to save the byte[] to a temporary file though.
    public void save(String name, byte[] file) throws IOException {

        File tmp = File.createTempFile(name, "tmp");
        FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(tmp, file);

            PutObjectRequest put = new PutObjectRequest(
                    configuration.getBucketName(), name, tmp);
            s3client.putObject(put);
    }

Comment: @Tim You got any solution for this?